# Number of times an audio file has been played using custom player

Tags: audio

I saw the question & answer to "How to get the number of times an audio file has been played" and I am looking for the same result, but I am not using the native WP audio player. I am using a custom theme that includes a custom player called Scamp player.

This is what's in the theme's PHP for the player:

```
if ( $panel_options && isset( $panel_options['scamp_player'] ) && $panel_options['scamp_player'] === 'on' ) {
    require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/post-types/scamp-player.php' );
```

Here's the code from the original that I would like to use:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        (function ($) {
            var srcs = []; // Array of sources already sent to cut down on posts to server.
            $('audio.wp-audio-shortcode, .wp-audio-playlist audio').on('play', function (event) {
                // this.src should be the url (guid) of the audio file
                if (this.src && $.inArray(this.src, srcs) === -1) {
                    srcs.push(this.src);
                    $.post( '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', {
                            action: 'wpse168584_audio_stats',
                            guid: this.src.replace(/\?.+$/, ''), // Remove any query vars.
                            nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wpse168584_audio_stats_' ); ?>'
                        }, null, 'json'
                    );
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
} );
function wpse168584_audio_stats() {
    $ret = array( 'error' => false );    
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'wpse168584_audio_stats_', 'nonce', false /*die*/ ) ) {
        $ret['error'] = __( 'Permission error', 'wpfm' );
    } else {
        if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['guid'] ) || ! ( $guid = $_REQUEST['guid'] ) ) {
            $ret['error'] = __( 'Params error', 'wpfm' );
        } else {
            global $wpdb;
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE guid = %s LIMIT 1', $guid );
            if ( $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql ) ) {
                // Use hex format to save space, 8 bytes for IPv4, 32 for IPv6.
                $ip = bin2hex( inet_pton( preg_replace( '/[^0-9a-fA-F:., ]/', '', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) );
                if ( ! ( $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true ) )
                || ! isset( $meta['plays_ips'] )
                || ! in_array( $ip, $plays_ips = explode( ';', $meta['plays_ips'] ) ) ) {
                    $plays_ips[] = $ip;
                    // If data getting too big, drop off oldest ip (FIFO).
                    if ( strlen( $meta['play_ids'] ) > 1000 ) array_shift( $plays_ips );
                    // Save as string to save space.
                    $meta['plays_ips'] = implode( ';', $plays_ips );
                    $meta['plays'] = isset( $meta['plays'] ) ? $meta['plays'] + 1 : 1;
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', $meta );
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    wp_send_json( $ret );
}    
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse168584_audio_stats', 'wpse168584_audio_stats' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse168584_audio_stats', 'wpse168584_audio_stats' );

add_filter( 'media_submitbox_misc_sections', function ( $arr ) {
    $arr['plays'] = __( 'Play Count:' );
    return $arr;
} );
```

How would I get the same results using this Scamp player?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a metabox with a custom field to add a counter to your song . As like

```
add_action( "add_meta_boxes", "amz_add_custom_meta_box" );
function amz_add_custom_meta_box() {
   global $post;
   if ( $post->post_type == 'music' ) {
      add_meta_box( "counter-meta-box", "Total Played", "_custom_meta_box_markup", "music", "side", "high", null );
   }
}
```

Then, there is a function on scamp_player i.e.

```
onTrackEnd: function() {}
```

you could write a Ajax request on this function and update your metafield. This function will be called when the track is ended.

Hope this helps!!
Happy coding